# Let $T$ be distributed as $S$, conditional on $S>0$. Express $h(u):= \mathbb E[u^T]$, the probability generating function of T, in terms of $g(u)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $g(u):= \mathbb E[u^S]$ is the probability generating function of a nonnegative integer-valued r.v. S satisfying $P(S>0)>0$. Let $T$ be distributed as $S$, conditional on the event $S>0$. Express $h(u):= \mathbb E[u^T]$, the probability generating function of T, in terms of $g(u)$.

Now, $h(u)= \mathbb E[u^T] =\mathbb E [\mathbb E[u^T|S>0]] $, how to continue from here?

Comment: Express $P(S=0)$ in terms of the generating function $g(u)$. Then, use $$h(u) = \mathbb{E} [u^S \mid S>0] = \frac{\mathbb{E} [u^S \cdot \chi_{S>0}]}{P(S>0)}, $$ where $\chi_{S>0}$ is the indicator of the event $\{ S > 0 \}$.

Comment: ...Using also the fact that $E(u^S\cdot\chi_{S>0})=E(u^S)-E(u^S\cdot\chi_{S=0})=g(u)-P(S=0)$.